# guard laravel - how can I pass an option to force polling to the listen rubygem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, laravel, guard, listen

I am using the guard-laravel package on my project in the hope of using sass. Unfortunately, I am also using vagrant for my development environment which uses Vitualbox shares to mount my web sites folders to the VM-  I say unfortunately because it appears that changes to the virtualbox shared folders are not picked up by the listen rubygem.

This, I believe, leaves me with two options:

1) Use samba to share folders - this is an option, but I suspect it may be a bit of a pain to get vagrant/chef to play nicely

or

2) force the listen rubygem into polling mode, now I have read that I can pass this in as a flag but since I am not manually launching the listen gem I dont know how I can do this.

Can anyone suggest how I might force the gem to always go into polling mode or if you know another way to make the listen gem watch my shared folders then that would be equally wonderful if not wonderfullier.